# jQuery document to toggle menu classes off

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm unable to close the mobile menu when a user clicks off. I use the mobileMenu function to toggle classes. I want to toggle these classes off through a document click event. Any thoughts? Thanks

Here is my code:

```
 $(document).click(function (event) {
    var _opened = $(".mobile-menu").hasClass("open");
    if ( _opened == true ) {
       $('.mobile-menu').toggleClass('open');
    }
  });


    function mobileMenu(trigger, target) {
        $(trigger).on('click', function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            $(this).find('i').toggleClass('icon-x')
            $(target).toggleClass('open');
        });
    }

    mobileMenu('.mobile-menu-toggle', '.mobile-menu');
```

Comment: if you are clicking off the element, surely all you need to do is remove the class rather than toggle it.  Also you want to stop propagation when clicking in the menu.  [See my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52383021/what-does-bootstrap-use-to-make-backdrop-passive/52383386#52383386), it's a similar - problem, except using an overlay for the click instead of the document

Comment: My current menu will not load. I think the document click is overriding the mobileMenu function. Is this something to do with stop propagation?

Comment: Most likely (but without seeing a [mcve] I wouldn't be able to tell for certain), but also why do you bind in a function - do you use that function multiple times for different elements?  if not then why not bind the click directly?